# Format multiple columns depending on the value of one

Tags: javascript, jquery, jqgrid

Can I use a custom formatter on a cell A to modify a cell B ?

Comment: This question is legit. I don't know why would you down vote it.

Comment: Could you include at least 2 items of data and describe more detailed what you do now and what you need to implement? All is possible, but one have to know more detailes about your problem. Do you use `datatype: "json", loadonce: true` or `datatype: "local"`? Which version of jqGrid you use (and can use)? Which fork of jqGrid you use: [free jqGrid](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid), commercial [Guriddo jqGrid JS](http://guriddo.net/?page_id=103334) or an old jqGrid in version <=4.7. Which columns you want to have in the grid? You write about "column A", columns Result, Count, Sum...

Comment: Typically you don't nee to loop through the data. Do you want to display *the part of data returned from the server* (the data filtered by "result")? You write about formatting... What you need exactly? For example one can change the color of some cells or some rows based on the content of some column or the property of input data. One can construct really *content* of the cells in the column based on the information from different propertries or diferent columns. What you need exactly.

Comment: @Oleg sure, i am creating a fiddle

Comment: @Oleg here is my fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/fo3wb58w/4/ what i want to achieve is take the string and turn it into json object and then loop through it, if the first element exist and is not null i want to put a green LED in the column withe the same name, if exist and null red LED, if doesn't exist nothing

Comment: @Oleg this is why i asked if we can do it with only one formatter one the data column that formats the other three

Comment: @Oleg am i making any sense ?

Comment: Sorry, but I still don't understand you. I asked you to include **at least 2 items of data**. jqGrid displays array or items. The current input data has really no sense. Why you have array of arrays with a lot of empty strings? Why you have JSON strings instead of objects? Do you need to read such strange formatted data, which you get from some foreign server or you can change the format of the data to make there more readable? In any way you should never fill the grid calling `addRowData` in the loop. It's the worst way to fill the grid. One should use `data` parameter (`data: mydata`).

Comment: Look at [here](http://free-jqgrid.github.io/getting-started/index.html) for the example of the simplest grid.

Comment: @Oleg i can change the data

Comment: @Oleg why is using a json string bad ?  The string is the result of a query from my database .

Comment: Typically you get the data which you load as object in server then the client JavaScript get the data via Ajax. One converts the object *for the transfair* to JSON string and then convert it back to object in the JavaScript. jQuery.ajax called with correct parameters will *deserialize* the JSON string back to the *object* and you get something like `[{pla:1, mco:null, sup: null}, {pla:2, mco:"x", sup: "abc"}]`, which you can use as the input for jqGrid. I asked you twice to provide at least 2 items of test data. You should answer on the questions if you want to get the answer on youth.

Comment: Please click on "edit" button below of your question, modify the text and include all information related to your question in the main text. You should describe the problem clear enough which input you have and which grid you need to create. You use "column A", Result,Count and Sum in the text of the question and absolute another names in the demo. It's unclear your main question about **formatting**: how the test input shoule be displayed/formatted?

Comment: @Oleg i can't change the format of my data it have to be a json string.

Comment: @Oleg why do you need more then one data row ? if it works for one  it will work for all .

Comment: You use permanently wrong terminology: formatter means [predefined formatters](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:predefined_formatter) or [custom formatters](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:custom_formatter). Where are exist callbacks `cellattr` and `rowattr`, which allows to set **atributes** like `class`, `style` and so on on cells of the column or on rows. Probably you need to use `rowattr`, but I'm not sure, because your test is still uncler.

Comment: You write in 1. about "if the first element exist" whithout including any example. Is it `"{\"pla\":1,\"mco\":null,\"sup\":null}"`? What is "the first element"? You write later "if exist" and "if doesn't exist" and it's unclear what you mean. One include typically test input data with some rows. You can describe on the example which row or cells should be red and which green. Moreover you should modify your demo to make the input more clear is it `var mydata = [{data: "{\"pla\":1,\"mco\":null,\"sup\":null}", "MCO": "", "PLA": "", "SUP": ""}];`? http://jsfiddle.net/fo3wb58w/5/

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/fo3wb58w/6/

Comment: @Oleg i am sorry. I guess my question should be this. Can i use a custom formatter on a cell A that can modify a cell B ?

Comment: @Oleg updated my question , sorry . That is what i really wanted to know

Comment: No you can't. The custom formatter of on a cell A can't access the cell B. You still don't want to describe what you want on an example. I'm afrade that you want still not what you asked. You can for example define *new formatter* as *one function* and you can use *the same function* in multiple columns (column A, column B and so on). The `options` parameter contains the information on which column it will be applied. The problem is: I can't provide any code which explains exactly *how* you can do what I guess what you really want, because I'm not sure that I understand you correctly.

Comment: @Oleg, you are right, give me one last chance, this is a fiddle that explains exactly what i need http://jsfiddle.net/fo3wb58w/12/ . I was just wondering isn't there a better way to do it, i mean in stead of putting a formatter on each cell ?  I ask this because i am already using a lot's of java script on my page and i want to avoid putting more if i can

Comment: I think that the last demo is already good enough. The improvement would be based on what version and what fork of jqGrid you would use. The current demo use old 4.6 version, which has some bugs in reading of *local data*. I'd recommend you to distinguish **reading of data** for pla, mco, sup, rex properties and **formatting o fthe cell**. Try to sort by some column or to filter by usage [filterToolbar](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:toolbar_searching) or search dialog and you will see what I mean. I recommend you to use `jsonmap` or `cell` of `jsonReader` to *read* better.

Comment: You can use, for example, `localReader: {repeatitems: true, cell: function (item) { var rowData = $.parseJSON(item.data); rowData.data = item.data; return rowData; } }`. Moreover, it's good always to define [unformat](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:custom_formatter#unformatting) if you use custom formatter. If you can change the format of input data then you can remove unneeded `MCO: "", PLA: "", SUP: "",REX:""` part from every item of data. I'm busy at the weekend, but I can try to help you later if it would be needed. I recommend you to upgrade to free jqGrid 4.13.4 too.

Comment: See http://jsfiddle.net/OlegKi/fo3wb58w/14/ as an example of usage. Try to sort by some columns here and you will see the difference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your original demo http://jsfiddle.net/fo3wb58w/12/ shows what you want. In general, you use already *one* formatter function shared by multiple columns. If you would click on the column header of the column `PLA`, `MCO`, `SUP` or `REX` you will see nothing happens. The problem is: you use `datatype: "local"`, which holds the internal **data** of the grid in the `data` and `_index` parameters. The `data` will be used during sorting and filtering/searching of the local data. Formatting is just the form to display the corresponding data. Thus I would recommend you to fill the column data for every column first and only then format the data. It will saves correct data in the `data` parameter and will allows to sort and filter the data.

The simplest modification of the demo will consist from including `localReader`

```
localReader: {
    repeatitems: true,
    cell: function (item) {
        var rowData = $.parseJSON(item.data);
        rowData.data = item.data; // include the original data too
        return rowData;
    }
}
```

and modification of your custom formatter to the following, for example,

```
function format (cellvalue) {
    if (cellvalue !== undefined) {
        return '<div class="led-box"><div class="' +
            (cellvalue !== null ? 'led-green' : 'led-red') +
            '"></div></div>';
    } else {
        return '';
    }
}
```

See http://jsfiddle.net/OlegKi/fo3wb58w/14/. Now we will fill the *data*, which allows us to sort there. I use in the demo the latest version of free jqGrid because jqGrid 4.6, which you used in the original demo has the bug with processing of `localReader` which has `repeatitems: true`.

More deep modification will be http://jsfiddle.net/OlegKi/fo3wb58w/15/

```
var mydata = [
        { data: "{\"pla\":1,\"mco\":null,\"sup\":null}" },
        { data: "{\"pla\":null,\"mco\":1,\"sup\":1}" },
        { data: "{\"pla\":1,\"rex\":null}" }
    ],
    sortRedGreen = function (value) {
        switch (value) {
            case 1:
                return 2;
            case null:
                return 1;
            default:
                return 0;
        }
    },
    formatRedGreen = function (cellvalue) {
        if (cellvalue !== undefined) {
            return '<div class="led-box"><div class="' +
                (cellvalue !== null ? 'led-green' : 'led-red') +
                '"></div></div>';
        } else {
            return '';
        }
    },
    templateRedOrGreen = {
        width: 48,
        sorttype: sortRedGreen,
        stype: "select",
        searchoptions: { value: "undefined:Undef;null:Null;1:1", noFilterText: "Any"},
        formatter: formatRedGreen
    };

$("#grid").jqGrid({
    data: mydata,
    autoencode: true,
    colModel: [
        { name: 'data', width: 250, search: false },
        { label: 'PLA', name: 'pla', template: templateRedOrGreen },
        { label: 'MCO', name: 'mco', template: templateRedOrGreen },
        { label: 'SUP', name: 'sup', template: templateRedOrGreen },
        { label: 'REX', name: 'rex', template: templateRedOrGreen }
    ],
    localReader: {
        repeatitems: true,
        cell: function (item) {
            var rowData = $.parseJSON(item.data);
            rowData.data = item.data; // include the original data too
            return rowData;
        }
    },
    iconSet: "fontAwesome",
    caption: "Stack Overflow Example"
}).jqGrid("filterToolbar");
```

It uses custom `sorttype` function which allow to reorder the possible value `undefined`, `null` and `1` during sorting. It uses `filterToolbar` with

```
stype: "select",
searchoptions: { value: "undefined:Undef;null:Null;1:1", noFilterText: "Any"}
```

to simplify filtering of the data.

Comment: Thanks you for your efforts. In my real life application i do not use local data, i use server side paging as i have 10000000 + possible rows :) . I will accept your answer although it didn't really answer my question :) My bad i didn't ask it properly. And btw i do not want to sort those columns. Thank you for your time and have a good week end

Comment: I didn't know we can use font awesome with jqgrid :)  so thanks for that

Comment: @zouza: You are welcome! You can take a look in [the article](http://free-jqgrid.github.io/getting-started/index.html) and in [the wiki](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid/wiki)

Comment: ok thanks i will. If i upgrade to the latest version will i have any regression problems ?

Comment: @zouza: Free jqGrid is compatible to old jqGrid 4.6/4.7 but it contains many enhancements. You should has no regression, but to have advantages of new features you should use it.